# User based restriction on a speficic row in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, permissions, spreadsheet

Is there a row based permission for a user in Google SpreadSheet?

For example, I have shared my spreadsheet among multiple users, now I want to restrict some rows. So that a specific row may not be visible to specific users.

I have other solutions to this. But I'm looking around for proper permission-based filters. Right now I'm able to find only editable permission for a range based filter.

Answer (score 1):

> So that a specific row may not be visible to specific users

no, this is not possible in Google Sheets

Comment: This is the correct answer; only one version of the sheet is viewable at a time and it is the same for everyone that opens the sheet.